# Classpath and portability

Tags: java, eclipse, classpath

I am new to Java and am using Eclipse to write Java code.

I've added lots of library (`.jar`) files as referenced libraries. I've also exported my project as a `JAR` file. My question is if I run this file on a computer where the referenced libraries are not at the same place as in my computer, will it run successfully?

I also made a `runnable JAR` file, whose size was much larger (~29 MB) as compared to the previous file (~24 KB).

Comment: You should look inside the "runnable JAR file" - I suspect it will include the contents of all the dependencies.

Comment: @JonSkeet yes, it does. But wouldn't just the smaller file work on other machines?

Comment: No, because then those other machines wouldn't have the code you're depending on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is if I run this file on a computer where the referenced libraries are not at the same place as in my computer, will it run successfully?

No.  You need to package the referenced JARs alongside your program JAR.  It would be inconvenient for the end-user to have to download all the libraries that your program depends on.  A couple of options, both possible using the Eclipse Export function.

1. Unpack all your dependent JARs and package them together with your code into one single executable JAR.
2. Specify in your program JAR manifest the classpath, which will contain relative paths to the location of your dependent JARs.  These could be for example in a `lib` folder.  The location of the `lib` folder relative to your program JAR would need to be the same for all your end-users, so it would make sense to package it all together.

Answer (score 1):

you can even bundle the reference library in the same jar.  So as you reduced the size to that extent i assume you removed those from the jar, which is not good approach in most cases. It is not recommended not to include referenced jar, unless you are 100% (not even 99.9%) sure those library WILL be in the system you would want to run.

**EDIT:**
to include the referenced jar in eclipse, you need to goto 
**project-properties>java-build-path>order-and-export**
here check whatever libraries you want.

Comment: But there is a problem. If I make a `runnable JAR` I've to specify a main class, but I don't want to do so. How can I bundle the libraries within the jar file (in Eclipse)?

Comment: no, its not necessary to have main-class. libraries don't have any. but if you want it to be runnable, you have to specify main class.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the way you package jars with the runnable jar app. if you do it inside the jar or outside it then you should make a classpath entry to your `manifest.mf`.